# How to Oracle XMLTYPE in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, ora-17004

One of the column is of the type XMLTYPE in Oracle database.
In my application, I want to persist the data and using Hibernate.

I did the following for mapping XMLTYPE in hibernate

1. Define the custom user type implementing UserType
2. The custom user type implementation is based on the blog link - http://community.jboss.org/wiki/MappingOracleXmlTypetoDocument
3. ut we are not using C3p0 connection pool and instead we are using DBCP

I am facing issue while creating the XMLType in the custom user type

```
XMLType.createXML(st.getConnection(),HibernateXMLType.domToString((Document) value));
```

where st is the preparedStatement passed to the method.

The **connection object returned by st.getConnection() is of the type org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnection**

**But the createXML method expects connection object only of the type oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection**

I also tried getting the getInnermostDelegate but this also does not work.

The XMLTYPE creation methods are in the included jar xdb.jar - will there be any changes depending on the versions included?

Thanks

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Got the SQLConnection object using the below code-

```
SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor extractor = new SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor();
PoolableConnection poolableConnection = (PoolableConnection) extractor
                .getNativeConnection(st.getConnection());
Connection sqlConnection = poolableConnection.getInnermostDelegate();
```

Now, the error message is **java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type**

Below is the over ridden method

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
            throws HibernateException, SQLException {

        SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor extractor = new SimpleNativeJdbcExtractor();
        PoolableConnection poolableConnection = (PoolableConnection) extractor
                .getNativeConnection(st.getConnection());
        Connection sqlConnection = poolableConnection.getInnermostDelegate();

        try {
            XMLType xmlType = null;
            if (value != null) {
                xmlType.createXML(sqlConnection, HibernateXMLType
                        .domToString((Document) value));

            }
            st.setObject(index, xmlType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new SQLException(
                    "Could not convert Document to String for storage");
        }
    }
```

**Left with no clue now...**

Comment: "I also tried getting the getInnermostDelegate but this also does not work." I always use getInnermostDelegate(); and it works. Please send error with getInnermostDelegate/* Connection oracleConnection = conn;

if (conn instanceof org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection) {
oracleConnection = ((org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate();
} */

Answer (score 0):

I faced a lots of problem using XMLType from java, I fixed this problem is a very simple way.

I changed the input data type from oracle DB side, from XMLtype to CLOB, then I easily pass CLOB and at the first line in the stored procedure; I built an XMLType from CLOB.

CLOB is very straight forward in java, just use it as String (`statement.setString(1, string);`)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this same problem, but mapped the XMLType column to java.lang.String in my entity, which simplified the solution.

I left a detailed, [step-by-step solution as an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282094/1601579).