# Retrieving oracle XMLType stored as binary XML from a resultset in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, xmltype

I outlined a solution to writing/reading to an Oracle XMLType column for Oracle 11g (specifically 11.2.0.1) if the XMLType column is stored as a CLOB, which is the default for 11.2.0.1.

**[REFERENCE ANSWER: Using oracle XMLType in a java spring hibernate scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578697/using-oracle-xmltype-column-in-hibernate/18282094#18282094)**

In SQLDeveloper, if you view the SQL tab within a table definition (table DDL) it defines the XML columns storage in 11.2.0.1 like this:

```
 XMLTYPE COLUMN "ATTRIBUTE_XML2" STORE AS BASICFILE CLOB
```

**Problem:**
In Oracle 11.2.0.2, the default storage type for XMLType is Binary XML, which is preferred for performance reasons.  It looks like this:

```
XMLTYPE COLUMN "ATTRIBUTE_XML2" STORE AS SECUREFILE BINARY XML
```

HOWEVER, once stored this way, my referenced solution no longer works for READING the XMLType column as XML from the database.  It returns some garbage from xmlType.getStringVal(), which I assume is the oracle binary encoded XML.

**Ultimate Problem**
I am unable to convert back from the oracle binxml format to a valid XML document.

I have tried the Oracle BinXMLProcessor, BinXMLStream, BinXMLDecoder and InfosetReader in [various configurations as outlined by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17604/adx_j_xmlbin.htm#BABBGHHH), but they seem to just read, rather than decode it - so it errors out.

Basic example within the nullSafeGet (see linked answer for context).

```
xmlType = (XMLType) rs.getObject(names[0]);
BinXMLProcessor xp = BinXMLProcessorFactory.createProcessor();
BinXMLStream bstr = xp.createBinXMLStream(xmlType.getInputStream());
BinXMLDecoder xdecode = bstr.getDecoder();
InfosetReader reader = xdecode.getReader();

while (reader.hasNext() && i < 25) {
    i++;
    reader.next();
    logger.debug("1 v:" + reader.getValue() + ", s:" + reader.getStandalone() + ", type: " + reader.getEventType() + ", " + reader.getDataLength());
}
```

I tried similar approaches, replacing xmlType.getInputStream() with xmlType.getBlobVal(178), xmlType.getBytesValue(), but they all throw an exception or return garbage data.

Huh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the catch, and it's not related to the code.

The proper nullSafeGet in the Hibernate UserType, as noted in the referenced answer is:

```
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

    if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace("  nullSafeSet: " + value + ", ps: " + st + ", index: " + index);
    }
    try {
        XMLType xmlType = null;
        if (value != null) {
            xmlType = XMLType.createXML(getOracleConnection(st.getConnection()), (String)value);
        }
        st.setObject(index, xmlType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Could not convert String to XML for storage: " + (String)value);
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:** when using a SECUREFILE BINARY XML column (not CLOB) you must use the most recent (11.2.0.2+) distribution of the xdb*.jar, which in this case is xdb6.jar (~257kb).  The earlier xdb*.jar (~136kb for 10.x) will still function, without tossing any exceptions even when incorrectly decoding BINARY XML.

**TL;DR**:  [Download xdb6.jar (~257kb) from the Oracle 11gR2 (11.2.0.3) JDBC drivers page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html).  Older xdb jars fail silently and will make you sad.