# XMLType (oracle), unit tests with in memory HSQL database and Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, unit-testing

I'm having problems with populating my unit test dataset with hibernate entities containing  an oracle "xmlType" attribute. Our module uses Spring framework (not boot)

Everything works fine except xmlType, if I switch these to simple "columns" all the unit test are passed.

Without any modifications I get this :

```
 org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: xmlType, at table: Message,
```

If I add that property to SessionFactory bean :

```
<property name="typeDefinitions">
            <array>
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.TypeDefinitionBean">
                    <property name="typeClass"
                        value="ourcompanyname.commons.persistence.hibernate.types.OracleXmlType" />
                    <property name="typeName" value="xmlType" />
                </bean>
            </array>
        </property>
```

I get another error :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2007
```

So I tried extending HSQLDialect

```
public class CustomDialect extends HSQLDialect {

    public CustomDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType(XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "xmlType");

    }

}
```

This gives me another error :

```
    2018-02-06 15:25:38,487 [ ERROR ] [ SchemaUpdate ] - Unsuccessful: create table Message [sql create query]
2018-02-06 15:25:38,487 [ ERROR ] [ SchemaUpdate ] - type not found or user lacks privilege: XMLTYPE
```

I don't get what could be wrong here, our columns are defined like this

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "xmlType")
private String content;
```

Comment: Have you seen this similar question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578697/using-oracle-xmltype-column-in-hibernate

Comment: Yes and the solutions don't seem to work

Comment: my bad my mapping was just wrong
`registerColumnType(oracle.xdb.XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "clob");
  registerHibernateType(oracle.xdb.XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "clob");`

in m y customDialect solved it...

Answer (score 0):

my bad my mapping was just wrong registerColumnType(oracle.xdb.XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "clob"); registerHibernateType(oracle.xdb.XMLType._SQL_TYPECODE, "clob"); in m y customDialect solved it...