# Oracle XmlType to stored procedure out parameter

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I am looking for a way to retrieve the output from oracle stored procedure using hibernate.  I am having trouble while setting the output expected from the procedure call.

The question is what is the equivalent of oracle's XmlType (Sys.XmlType) in hibernate.

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11578697/266304) Or maybe you could retrieve the XML as a string instead - using `XMLType.getStringVal` or `.getClobVal`?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole Thanks for your response.  We are actually trying to find a .class type that we can use in registeroutparemeter while making a stored procedure call.  All reference we see in web are more tightly aligned with hibernate and entity.  Our stored procedure invocation doesn't do anything with the entities

Comment: Did you figure this out?